# How to compare google protobuf ByteString

Tags: sorting, protocol-buffers, string-comparison, protobuf-java

In google protobuf, it provides a type called ByteString, I checked the doc: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString there is no comparison method for use. Let's say:

```
List<ByteString> input;
Collections.sort(input, (a, b) -> // How to compare them?
```

Comment: What do you expect to compare? A byte string is an text string. How would you want to sort two of those arrays?